# net.ucanaccess.triggers.TriggerException: Table does not exists. :Z_2015_02_24

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, ucanaccess, jackcess

i have problems inserting records into a table via UCanAccess.
My insert looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO [2015_02_24_15_52_29_926_test_schema] ( ... )
```

The insert will be fired by a standard `java.sql.Statement`.

UCanAccess internally converts the sql. This is the result:

```
INSERT INTO Z_2015_02_24_15_52_29_926_test_schema (...)
```

Just why does UCanAccess add a 'Z' to the table name?

I debugged the code an found out that the change happens in `SQLConverter.escape(sql)` in the class `SQLConverter` provided by UCanAccess.

Answer (score 2):

UCanAccess aims to support table  names like 2015_02_24_15_52_29_926_test_schema. In order to do this, it needs to use an internal naming remap.
There may be  some bug in the very old versions about it, but an INSERT like
`insert into [2015_02_24_15_52_29_926_test_schema] values(1,'f')` works nicely
in the latest versions(I've just tried with the 2.0.9.2 and 2.0.9.3).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I use the latest version but it doesn't work like that for me. Nevertheless, it's a satisfying solution for me to prepend a "TBL_" on the table name.

Comment: That's strange, I also developed a number of junit test  about this specific case and all of them run succesfully. Anyway, if you can improve the naming, just do it.

Answer (score 1):

UCanAccess doesn't allow numbers at the beginning of the table name.

Simply use `TBL_2015...` as your table name.